# Refresh em jframe automaticamente

Tags: java, lista, jframe

Iniciarei um projeto onde irei fazer o controle de filas em java, filas normais mesmo, como se você chegasse no banco e visse no telão seu nome.

Vou passar um resumo do projeto pra ficar mais claro.

Tenho 10 computadores, cada um pertence a uma pessoa, essas pessoas solicitam algo simultaneamente. Em uma outra jframe irá exibir quem solicitou primeiro, irá exibir o nome da pessoa e o tempo que a mesma solicitou, assim que a mesma for atendida o nome dela é retirada da fila, por exemplo:

```
Solicitante | Tempo que fez a solicitação
João        | 2:45
Roberto     | 1:58
Olivia      | 0:50
Pedro       | 0:15
```

Porém preciso exibir isso em tempo real, ou seja, irá apresentar o tempo solicitado em tempo real e também assim que alguem entrar na fila ou sair também acontecerá em tempo real

Preciso uma forma de dar um refresh na jframe que irá realizar essa exibição de forma automática, seja a cada 2 segundos, ou 3... enfim

Tenho a necessidade de realizar isso em JAVA

Alguém sabe algum metodo que eu consiga programar esse refresh ou alguma forma de fazer isso de forma automática?

Comment: O que você já fez? Adicione o código na pergunta. é bem provável que o que você precise é de um Observer.

Comment: Bom dia, eu irei iniciar o projeto no periodo da tarde, porém não sei como posso desenvolver essa parte do refresh, pensei em usar o Timer do java.

Comment: É importante você começar primeiro, porque ai teremos um ponto de onde te ajudar. Explicar isso tornaria a resposta ampla demais.

Comment: pensei em fazer algo assim

Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      updateRecords();
   }
});

timer.setDelay(3000); // 
timer.start();

porém isso num action, precisava que fosse executado automaticamente e constantemente

Comment: Que nem te disse, a resposta ainda seria ampla, pois não tem de onde partir. Creio que existam várias formas de fazer isso, mas se você já adicionar algo que já tentou fazer, ai fica mais facil responder.

Answer (score -1):

Isso vai depende do componente que você usar para mostrar as informações. Sempre quando houver uma nova solicitação apenas atualize o componente que você esta usando, quando for remover a solicitação então atualize novamente, vc nunca deve dar um refresh no jframe inteiro, apenas no componente que a informação deve ser atualizado. Começe a fazer seu projeto, cada componente gráfico tem uma forma de atualizar a informação, quando não conseguir faça uma nova pergunta informando o que vc esta utilizando.

Exemplo: um `JList` vc usa o método `fireContentsChanged(...)`, ja em um `JTable` você usa o método `fireTableDataChanged()`.

Você não precisa de um timer que atualiza em um determinado intervalo de tempo. Se você sabe o momento que o evento ocorre então é só implementar a atualização dos componentes.